# React Hooks with button on clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, webstorm

I just started with React hooks and trying to have 3 buttons which I can click on and it should tell me how many times it was clicked. I can make them separately working but that's not performant.

Therefore I was looking for making it useful with just two classes: one for the buttons and the other one for the counter part. But now I'm struggling with calling the functions and separating (which one is clicked) the buttons.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Counter from "./Counter";
const Buttons = () => {
  const HandleClick = () => {
    setCounter(count + 1);
  };
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button className={"GoodBtn"} onClick={HandleClick}>
        Good
      </button>
      <button className={"NeutralBtn"} onClick={HandleClick}>
        Neutral
      </button>
      <button className={"BadBtn"} onClick={HandleClick}>
        Bad
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const teller = () => count + 1;
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Statistics</h2>
      <p>Good {Buttons.count}</p>
      <p>Neutral {Buttons.count}</p>
      <p>Bad {Buttons.count}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Counter from "./Counter";
const Buttons = () => {
    const[count,setCounter]= useState({
         good: 0,
         neutral: 0,
         bad: 0
    });

     const HandleClick = (key) =>{
         setCounter(state => ({...state, [key]: state[key] + 1}));
     }

     return (
         <div>
             <button className={"GoodBtn"} onClick={HandleClick('good')}>Good</button>
             <button className={"NeutralBtn"} onClick={HandleClick('neutral')}>Neutral</button>
             <button className={"BadBtn"} onClick={HandleClick('bad')}>Bad</button>
        
         <Counter counts={count} />
       </div>
    )
}

export default Buttons;




import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Buttons from "./Buttons";

const Counter = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Statistics</h2>
            <p>Good {props.counts.good}</p>
            <p>Neutral {props.counts.neutral}</p>
            <p>Bad {props.counts.bad}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just do `Buttons.count`. Buttons is a React component, which needs to be created first, like: `<Buttons />`.

If you want to wrap your button component with a counter you could just do:

```
const CountableButton = ({ onCounterChange, ...props }) => {
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    //to correctly change state variable based on previous value
    setCounter((prevCounter) => prevCounter + 1); 
  };

  //Every time count changes trigger the onCounterChange function
  React.useEffect(() => {
    onCounterChange(count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <button {...props} onClick={handleClick}>
      Good
    </button>
  );
};
```

And you will use it like:

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Button clicked {count} times</h2>
      <CountableButton onCounterChange={(value) => setCount(value)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```